# jQuery for getting a Textarea's Input

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
textareaID = 'comment_content_300'
textareaValue = $('#' + textareaID).val();
```

What I can't figure out is, sometimes this works sometimes it doesn't. It does work when the page loads with the form that uses the above.

It does not work when the site is loaded, and an ajax load injects the commenting form that uses the above, it returns nothing, blank, not unidentified, just blank.

Any ideas?

**UPDATING WITH CODE**

JS

```
$('.new_comment').live('submit', function() {

    textareaID = $(this).find('textarea').attr('id');
    commentableID = textareaID.replace('comment_content_', '');
    textareaValue = $('#' + textareaID).val();
    textareaValue = jQuery.trim(textareaValue);
    .
    .
console.log(textareaValue);
```

returns empty

```
    ajax call doesn't happen until down here
```

HTML

```
<div class="write-comment">
 <textarea class="comment_content_bigbox" cols="40" id="comment_content_297" name="comment[content]" placeholder="Write your reply here..." rows="20" style="color: black; ">
 </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this except put onto the page from the AJAX call along with the form, or was this code around before the form arrives via AJAX?

Comment: Can you post the code of your AJAX call? Maybe you're calling `$("#comment_content_300")` before it completes?

Comment: This code was around BEFORE the injected content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell for sure without seeing more code, but I'd guess that instead of calling this code in the callback to the AJAX request, you're calling it *after* the request.

If that's right, then this is because the code that comes *after* the request does not wait for the response before it executes. That's why `$.ajax()` allows callback functions.

Something like:

```
var textareaID, textareaValue;

$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl',
    success: function(d) {
        $('body').append(d);
        textareaID = 'comment_content_300';
        textareaValue = $('#' + textareaID).val();
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Issue was with duplicate IDs.

Comment: this is all happening way before the ajax call. I use this to check the val() length making sure it's GT 1 before submitting via ajax

Comment: @Anapprentice: You're certain that the `textareaID` is correct? Have you tested the length of the resulting jQuery object? `alert($('#' + textareaID).length);` EDIT: Sorry, just noticed you're getting directly from the textarea. Still I'd do the alert.

Comment: I'm injecting the new HTML which contains the ability to comment via $('#panel1').html('div ...... any issues with that?

Comment: @AnApprentice: And you're targeting the correct `<textarea>` right? The reason I ask is that the selector uses `.new_comment`, but the HTML you provided shows `class='write_comment'`. Regarding injecting new content, I don't think so, but would need a fuller picture of what's going on. Once new content has been added to the DOM, it is just as accessible as content that was there from the start.

Comment: ya i think so, something else must be going on because after the comment submits, the server responds with ("#cmtList_297").append(.....  ANd this to doesn't work even though #cmtList_297 is on the page and was injected by jquery.

Comment: @AnApprentice: Wish I could be more help, but I'm just not sure what the issue would be. I guess I should just delete this answer, but if you can think of any relevant information to add to the question, I'd take another look. Sorry.

Comment: ok hit me with a fish. Figured out why but not yet how to fix. My app has 3 panels. The 3'rd panel is the one we are talking about now which is where you can commment on a post. probelm is the first panel contains a news_feed type thing which shows the comment as an activity which uses the same ID. issue here is that the ID exists in multiple places.

Comment: That ID in the feed panel is hidden/not visible. is there a way to tell jQuery look for the ID that is visible?